# toggle skips/misses 2nd sidebar

Tags: angularjs, toggle

Today's bogglement! I have two sidebars and a main content area. When I click on a button to expand the page, the sidebars should go away and the main content area spreads to 100%. (I'm trying to do something like what quandl.com does in its api displays, which is totally nifty.)

This should be really simple! I just add a class of 'apponly', which set the main-content to 100% and the sidebars to display:none. In my controller, I've got:

```
$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.displayed = !$scope.displayed;
}
```

and in my html, I've got basically:

```
<div class="sidebar left" ng-class="{'apponly' : displayed }">
    --something something--
</div>
<div class="main-content" ng-class="{'apponly' : displayed }">
    <button class="btn btn-info device" ng-click="toggle()">[icon]</button>
    --something something--
</div>
<div class="sidebar right" ng-class="{'apponly' : displayed }">
    --something something--
</div>
```

...but it consistently only applies the class 'apponly' to the first sidebar and main content, and leaves the second sidebar intact (wrapped around to the next line, but still right there, w/no class of 'apponly' applied).

I tried to set up a plnk (http://plnkr.co/edit/ER4TPGexGnZ8knb4ThXQ?p=preview) but it won't work at all [okay that was a stupid oversight, now it does work except now I'm even more confused]. What really simple obvious thing am I totally missing here?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to specify ng-app and ng-controller as well in the view.

Comment: doh. it's been one of those days. thanks, changing.

Answer (score 0):

AS PSL said, juste update your plunkr to `<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">` and it will work. It actually does what you were expecting, so the issue is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I might as well answer since I (sort of) figured it out, and you never know, I might not be the only one baffled by such behavior.

It's tied to the animation. If you take the animation away, then everything behaves. You add it back in, and things get wacky again.

Why is this? I have no idea. But when I took the animation off the sidebars (so they simply disappear immediately), then the right-hand sidebar doesn't get pushed to the next line and end up remaining despite the added-class that should make it disappear. From behavior at least, it seems that the browser is trying to render animation at the same time the css-class is trying to make the section disappear. Which doesn't make any sense, b/c this works fine in other places, but all I know is that if you leave the animation on the main (middle) part, and turn it off on the sidebars, then everything behaves properly.

I'm not counting this as an answer, though, since it's more of a "well, that fixed it, if inadequately," which is less of an answer and more of a workaround left here for posterity, the enlightenment of any confused devs behind me, and the entertainment of any senior devs wandering through.